# Saved regression output of a nested regression

Tags: r, tidyr, broom

I am trying to export a regression output of a nested regression, created using `broom` and `map`.

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out=10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
female <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
smoker <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
dta <- tibble(year = year, group = group, female = female, smoker = smoker)

mods <- dta %>%
  nest(data = c(-year)) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~ glm(smoker ~ female*group, data = .,
                                 family = binomial(link = "probit"))))

## export mods

## upload mods
```

1. How do I save mods?
2. Once it is saved, how can I load it into to the global environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
saveRDS(mods, "/tmp/model.rds") # choose here the path to the wanted file

mods <- readRDS("/tmp/model.rds")
```

Comment: yes! i tried this, but it is REALLY time-consuming. I basically need to force-quit Rstudios in order to get out of it. Is there another option?

Comment: Well, on my computer it takes 843ms, that is less than 1 second! So, it is hard to conceive such a time as long! However, you may want to consider to create a ramdisk: To save and read directly to and from your RAM (memory).

Comment: Moreover, it seems there is no faster way: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/git2rdata/vignettes/efficiency.html

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will try this then.